# JQuery not working to add css class

Tags: jquery, css

I need to change the background for the menu item of the active page.
I trying to achieve this with JQuery and CSS.

My code is:
HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li id="header"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a> </li>
   <li>|</li>
   <li><a href="About.aspx">About</a> </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.nav li.active {
  background-color:green;
}
.nav li.active a {
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  background-color:green;
 }
```

And finally the JQuery I am using for this is as below.

```
$(function () {
  setNavigation();
  /* below statement is just to verify if jquery working at all*/
  $('#header').css("background-color", "green"); 
});

function setNavigation() {
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
  path = decodeURIComponent(path);            
  $(".nav a").each(function () {               
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (path.substring(0, href.length) == href) {
      $("a").closest('li').addClass('active');
      /* below statement is just to verify if jquery working*/
      $('#header').css("background-color", "green");                 
    }
  });
}
```

I tried to debug this is using firebug still couldn't find the mistake.
I'm a newbie to JQuery and This is not working (might be a silly mistake) :( 
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Any errors in your console? Throw a console statement before your `if` statement to verify that the condition is being met.

Comment: If your header never comes green, it's because your condition is not good. Try to modify it by checking if the href is include in the path like this : if (path.indexOf(href) >= 0)

Comment: It worked.. :D Thanks a ton Mathieu. and also changed "a" to this. Working and looking gr8. :D

Answer (score 2):

When you're in an `.each` loop, `$(this)` refers to the object currently being iterated on. You want to add the class to the *current* anchor, not *all* anchors. So, you're going to want to change the following line:

Change `$("a").closest('li').addClass('active');`

To this line:

```
$(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
```

Comment: I have tried that too. Its still not working. I added "a" purposely to see if the class is added at all.

Comment: @AmrutaChitale Are you sure it's even making it that far in the code? Put an `alert` box where it says `$('a').closest('li')....` Because I think it's not making it past your check on the `href` line

Answer (score 2):

`$("a").closest('li').addClass('active');` will always do the same thing regardless of what page you're on. It will add the `active` class to **every** `li` which has an anchor as a child, because you're selecting **every** anchor on the page with `$("a")`.

Perhaps you wanted something like this:

```
$(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
```